# Does the Wii have a system for free (non-browser) games?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I just got a Wii with Wii Sports Resort and two Motion Plus controllers, but don't want to spend any more money on games for a while.

Does the Wii, like Steam and XBox Live, have a system for downloading and playing free games or demos?

I could probably play Flash games in the browser, but that kind of misses the point! :)

Answer (score 6):

The Nintendo channel provides downloadable demos for the DS (like a download station you'd see in a GameStop or so). The WiiWare shop area in the Shop Channel supposedly has some downloadable demos, but not a whole bunch (if any). Nintendo is fairly stingy about demos...

Another option may be to just install the [Homebrew Channel](http://hbc.hackmii.com/) and whatever [homebrew applications](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/List_of_homebrew_applications) you feel like trying out.

Other than that, the Wii isn't very free-gamer friendly. A $20 Wii card will net you 2 to 4 games off the shop on average, though. Might be worth the investment, even if you're trying to play on the cheap.

Comment: The homebrew channel is definitely the way to go. Somebody even made a port of Desert Bus!

Comment: And OpenTTD! It even supports multiplayer.